# Lync using SQL 2008 R2 SP1 - Publish Topology error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, lync

Error that shows in the web page opened by the Topology builder:

> Error: An error occurred:
>   "Microsoft.Rtc.Common.Data.SqlConnectionException" "A network-related
>   or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

**Looking in the log file: ( I assume this is the acutal error making it STOP)**

> Installed SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility version is 8.05.1054
>   Error: SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility is not installed or its
>   version is not high enough. SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatability SP2
>   or higher must be installed.

I have installed SQLServer2005_BC_x64.msi from [MS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24793), and cant seem to find this SP2 version.

SQL server is a 2008 R2 SP1.
I have also tested with a 2008 SP3 SQL server same error.

Named pippes output via ( OSQL /L)

> ```
> SQL-2008-1
> SQL2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Is the topology already published or are you publishing it for the first time? This looks like  Topology Builder can't communicate with your SQL server. Can you check that it's listening on Named Pipes?

Comment: Its a first time publish. If you look at the last error thats the one in the log file.